# Moving a website to a new host - How will this affect the existing SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, web-hosting

I have a website (e.g. somesite.com ) that I want to move this to another hosting company (domain name will stay the same). The existing website has a Comodo SSL certificate.

My question is about moving the SSL cert. Once I've moved the site and re-pointed DNS to the new host (and it's all propagated), I want to setup a new SSL cert with Let's Encrypt on the new host. Can I just leave the old SSL cert (Comodo) to expire ?

*(I'm doing this on behalf of someone else and they don't know where the details for the old SSL cert are, so I have no way of turning it off / deleting it.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the existing SSL certificate.

You just need to download you ssl certificate again with uploading new CSR. Follow below points if any issue you can take the hosting provide customer care help.

1. Generate the new CSR from your new hosting provider.
2. upload the CSR on your existing comodo login.
3. and then download the certificate for your site
4. upload this certificate to your new hosting provider.

Comment: hi aayushkamboj, many thanks for your reply. But I don't have any details of the existing SSL cert.  Thats my problem. If I setup a new cert on the new host, will the old cert (that will just get left - as I can't do anything to it), will this have any adverse effect ?

Comment: No you will not get effected with shifting a new SSL certificate. Not any issue you can go for new ssl purchase. Steps will remain same as above in the answer. The existing SSL certificate will not create any problem but if you have the old email id (Registered with Comodo) you can fetch the certificate detail from Comodo. Any query comment below.

Comment: thanks aayushkamboj, unfortunately I'm not allowed to up vote yet ( not enough reputation points). but I'll certainly comeback and upvote once I'm allowed